# How to make rest calls with a web browser

Tags: web-services, rest

How can i call a restfull web service by a  web browser if i have complex objects like hashmap or arraylist on the server side.I have found sample java clients but no help for doing it from web browser..
For instance if my web service waiting an arraylist of string objects how to differentiate this from a service which expects more than one string parameters on the input url.

Answer (score 1):

That very much depends on what the server accepts as the body of your HTTP request and what it can return. In REST, there is no such thing as a List of Strings. You pass and receive Representations of Resources.

So what are your Resources? What are their Representations?

Comment: Actually i was trying to understand how rest works and making some basic trials.For this I exposed an service which basically iterates and append over incoming arraylist of string objects and returns this appended string.basically its signature like public String append(Arraylist<String> input).I am using axis 1.5.2, and tomcat 6 to expose this service.and when i look at wsdl i see the arraylist described as anytype.

Comment: What you describe is logic behind a service. Perhaps you cou add some code to your question so we can see what you are trying to do. What are your Resourced? What are the URLs and requests you use to access them?

Comment: `String append(Arraylist<String> input)` is the signature of a Java method. That has nothing to do with REST.

Comment: here is the code  public String append(ArrayList<String> input){
  StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
  for (String s : input)
   output.append(s);
  return output.toString();
 } and here is the url I am using http://localhost:8080/WStrial/service/append?input=one&input=two&input=three   Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that is the logic beind your Java method. But where is the stuff related to REST? You said you "expose" this method. How do you do this?

Comment: I have used eclipse's create web service facility to expose this method as web service. axis2 1.5.2 and tomcat 6 is used.

Comment: OK, perhaps you should read the basics about REST. Try http://www.xfront.com/REST-Web-Services.html before using some IDEs tools that work magic.

Comment: actually i came to that point by reading an article about rest in which writer was shoving how to make basic calculation with primitive types.and i tried to see if it works on collections too.Anyway i see that the things i am trying to do is not comply with the aim of REST.i will read this article too.thank you.